# Inserting ASCII symbols into a String (Swift)

Tags: swift, string, utf-8, ascii

I'm trying to insert a symbol with ASCII code 255 (Telnet IAC) into a String, but when converting the data back to utf8 I'm getting a different symbol:

```
var s = "\u{ff}"
print(s.utf8.count) // 2
try! s.write(toFile: "output.txt", atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
```

The file contains `C3 BF`, not `FF`. I've also tried using

```
var s = "\(Character(UnicodeScalar(255)))"
```

but this produced the same result. How to escape it properly?

Comment: @LeoDabus Could you give an example? "\u{0xff}" doesn't compile.

Comment: @LeoDabus `var s = "\u{255}"` also produces `C3 BF` in utf8 view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASCII defines 128 characters from 0x00 to 0x7F. 0xFF (255) is not included.

In Unicode, U+00FF (in Swift, "\u{ff}") represents "ÿ" (LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIARESIS).
And its UTF-8 representation is 0xC3 0xBF. See [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), characters with code point from U+0080 to U+07FF are represented with two-byte sequence.
Also you need to know that 0xFF is not a valid byte in UTF-8 byte sequence, which means you cannot get any 0xFF bytes in UTF-8 text file.

If you want to output "\u{ff}" as a single-byte 0xFF, use ISO-8859-1 (aka ISO-Latin-1) instead:

```
try! s.write(toFile: "output.txt", atomically: true, encoding: .isoLatin1)
```